# How many points do the skill upgrades cost?

Tags: the-last-of-us

How many skill points do each of Joel's skill upgrades cost? Do the costs change across difficulties (aside from Shiv Master not being available on Easy and Listen Mode Distance not being available on Survivor and Grounded)?

This question applies equally to the Remastered version of the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note, does not change based on difficulty*

```
| Skill                | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Total |
| Maximum Health       | 50      | 100     | N/A     | 150   |
| Listen Mode Distance | 20      | 30      | 50      | 100   |
| Crafting Speed       | 25      | 30      | 50      | 105   |
| Healing Speed        | 30      | 40      | 50      | 120   |
| Weapon Sway          | 50      | 100     | N/A     | 150   |
| Shiv Master          | 75      | 100     | N/A     | 175   |
| ---------------------------------------------------------- |
| All Skills Combined  | 225     | 400     | 150     | 800   |
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. You may want to consider that while the costs of the individual upgrades don't change based on difficulty, the total cost does, since some skills aren't available. On Easy the total is 625 (no Shiv Master), and Survivor/Grounded is 710 (no Listen Mode Distance).